# Implementing a custom repo cycle: git pull, modify, svn commit

Tags: git, svn, github

I'm in unusual working environment and I do not have the authority to change it. The cycle as the following:

1. fetch updates from Git.
2. Make some changes locally.
3. Commit the changes to svn.

Usually the changes committed to the svn arrive to the Git repo sometime later.

I've looked for a solution and non worked. For example, I did the following:

```
$ svn checkout <svn_url>
$ cd repo_name
$ git init
$ git remote add <git_repo>
$ echo "**/.svn" > .gitignore
$ git add *
$ git fetch
$ git merge origin/master
error: Untracked working tree file '.gitignore' would be overwritten by merge.
fatal: read-tree failed
```

How to handle such a cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Use [git svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html):

```
git svn clone -s <svn_url>
cd repo_name
#work#work#work
git svn rebase
git svn dcommit
```

Comment: I need to clone github not svn. Also, how to fetch from github then commit ti svn? Th cycle you provided clones from svn and it doesn't show how to fetch.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Fetching from GitHub the usual way you would fetch gift.

Comment: So I start with: git clone <git_repo> ?